# Static class variables are created when Static methods are being called - Java

Tags: java, model-view-controller, static, controller

I have a controller class that has both static and non-static variables and methods.

```
public class Controller 
{
    // Model that will be used throughout the program
    private static Model model;
    private static ArrayList<Model> modelList = new ArrayList<Model>();

    // User Views
    private static OpenProgramView initialView = new OpenProgramView();
    private DriverProfileView driverProfileView;
}
```

There is also a static method that I need so that other classes can access it without a controller instance. The following is the call upon this method:

```
int askYear = Controller.getModel().getYear();
```

The issue I am having, is that when I use the previous line of code, it seems to call a new instance of the private static object - OpenProgramView. I know this because it pops up during testing when it shouldn't. I also changed other views from non-static to static to see what would happen and they also pop up when I use the static method, but the non-static views were not popping up.

My question - why is this happening? It seems that when I call a static method it is creating a new instance of all of the static class variables in controller and is creating an issue.

Edit:

I didn't specify that this only happens when I am testing this specific snippet of code. When this problem occurred I had not yet created a Controller object, thus the first time I touch the Controller class is with the call to the static method.

When I run the program out of test mode and actually use it for functional purposes - a Controller object has already been created at the creation of the program, thus, this issue doesn't occur once I call the static method, because it isn't the first time I've "touched" the class. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Read about static initialization in Java classes

Comment: This problem should not appear Probably you're doing something else in `getModel` static method that you're not showing, thus generating the problem.

Comment: Add more description please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because **the first time you will touch a class** (calling a method, accessing a field or creating an object) all **the static fields will be initialized**.

This is guaranteed by the Java Language Specification and you cannot really do much about it:

- either change the modifier to not static or
- initialize your views lazily

Comment: Yes, good theory, but OP's problem is different: *It seems that when I call a static method it is creating a new instance of all of the static class variables*

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza: read the answer carefully, he's correct. Static variables are tied to the .class instance itself. When a class is first loaded by the class loader, all of the static fields will be initialized. This is part of the reason why you should never rely on statics to wire up your stuff - initialization order can mess things up very badly. Use a dependency injection framework like Guice or Spring instead.

Comment: @Gergely that's why I said *good theory* but that doesn't provide a real solution for the problem. That just confirms that OP's problem is somewhere else. A solution will be: *move this static elements outside of the controller* or something similar. AFAICS, this is just a very long comment, not an answer.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza The question is literally "Why is this happening?". The answer explains why it is happening.